# Webm video simply not playing

Tags: html, html5-video, webm

Hi I have viewed the other questions about this and none of the problems seem related. I am trying to simply play a webm video inside an html video tag and it wont appear in any browser. I have played mp4 in chrome and ff with no issue, and mov in safari with no issue.

Here is docs I have referenced:
[webm reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AYXm.png)

And here is the latest implementation of my code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>SpinCoin!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

</head>

<body>

  <!-- <img src="picture.gif" style="height: 100%; width:100%"> -->

  <video id="vid" width="320" height="440" autoplay>
      <source src="anim.webm" type="video/xwebm">
    </video>

</body>

</script>

</html>
```

As you can see, I am trying something very simple here. I have tried video type as both "video/webm" and "video/x-webm", and I have tried including the codecs.

--The reason I insist on webm is that I need a transparent background, if there is another way to do this that is also welcome!

Comment: also I know in my code snippet I accidentally have the typo "type='video/xwebm'", that is not the issue as i said I have tried a few different type tags to no avail, thanks!

Comment: What do your web dev tools say? Particularly the network panel, or about:media-internals in chrome? Are you sure your video is correctly pointed by the uri? What when you try to read the video directly from the browser (drag&drop as new tab)? Are you sure you did encode the video correctly?

Comment: it is the correct path because I have used the same with other videos in other formats in this exact code. If I open the file alone in the browser it says it is corrupt, so I guess there's the problem. This was shared to me through Google Drive, and it works when i play it in the browser from Drive. So something happens to it when I download it from drive...any suggestions as to what? Thanks

Comment: and it only happens with the webm format. My business partner shared the same exact video with me the same way in mov, mp4, and webm, and webm is the only one that corrupts when downloaded

Comment: No, no concrete idea on what happend, probably an issue while downloading your file, try again, ask a checksum of the original file and compare it with yours. Not so much we can do from here to help you. Oh and IIRC only chrome and FF do support webm with alpha channel, so if it is for transparency, and that you want to support other browsers, you might have to use a double buffered video + canvas compositing trick.

Comment: Yea I tried that trick and I kept getting the error that getContext is not a function on a canvas object...so we decided to try different formats. Like I said we covered safari getting mov to work with transparent background, so I thought the webm would come smoothly as well...nope! well thanks for the input!